# In chapter 101 of Stone Ocean, How can Stone Free decode binary code?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Spoilers for JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Part 6: Stone Ocean (Jail House Lock! arc)

---

Emporio gives Jolyne a sheet of handwritten binary code and wants her to print it out. Jolyne takes this and prints out a picture using her stand.

I can't understand how she manages to decode it by herself. Star Platinum can quickly draw a photo-realistic image of a fly it saw but that doesn't apply here. Stone Free is "decoding" something, not copying.

How can Stone Free decode binary code?

---

The sheet of binary code:

[image: Emporio holding the encoded picture]

Printout:

[image: Jolyne's decoded picture]

Answer (score 3):

#### Stone Free actually *is* copying rather than decoding here.

Emporio's sheet of binary numbers isn't a coded message in the way that, say, [Bacon's cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher) uses "00000" to represent the letter "A", "00100" to represent the letter "E", and so on. It's literally binary text in the sense that there are only two possible values: 0 or 1; on or off; white or black.

Say the numbers written on the sheet looked like this:

```
000000
010010
000000
100001
011110
000000
```

If I told you to replace each "0" with a period and each "1" with a pound/hash symbol, you'd get:

```
......
.#..#.
......
#....#
.####.
......
```

See the smiley? :)

This is basically how Jolyne turns the binary numbers into an image with Stone Free: replace each "0" with one shape, and each "1" with a second shape, and a pattern emerges. In your second image, the shaded areas have a white "1" superimposed while the unshaded areas have a black "0" superimposed; my opinion is that the numbers are a visual aid for the reader's benefit, while Jolyne could be forming her string into shapes that create a high contrast between light and dark.

[The anime adaptation of this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVjCM2_dIYI) uses a more digital representation, with Jolyne making her string travel underneath each "0" and above each "1", moving vertically between numbers whenever they change to the other value.